# CQRS and Data Access Auditing

Tags: design-patterns, cqrs

How does the CQRS pattern deal with data access auditing?  Or Can it?

Let me give some background:

I have a distributed system.  It has several "Sections".  Each section handles part of the business.  (One does orders, another does billing, and another customers etc.)

I had planned to have each section send messages of business events to each other (i.e. order created, new customer registered etc).  Then the events could be stored off and replayed in an CQRS fashion.

I had also planned for each section to have a database of the data that they need from the other sections (Orders would keep a basic list of customers, billing would have a simple list of orders etc).  This data would be obtained via the business event messages.

I know that is not "True" CQRS.  But I think my question applies to CQRS all the same.

**So, in CQRS, how does auditing data access and data security work?  Do you just have to trust that all down stream systems will audit correctly?  (A very long stretch of trust)**

My Architect did not like CQRS for this reason.  Instead we are going to go with a service in each section of the distributed system that will field requests for data.  That way auditing (and security) can be done at a central (controlled) location.

**So, does CQRS have a strategy for auditing data access that I don't see?  Or is CQRS just for systems where data does not need to be controlled?**  (Or do I totally miss the point of CQRS?)

Just in case it matters: I am working with Visual Studio 2010, C# 4, .NET 4, WCF 4 and NServiceBus 2.6

Comment: Hi, have you found answer to you question? I'm just thinking on implementing CQRS and came up with the same (similar) question - for me it seams like "auditing" violates CQRS. But on the other side, if my "Query stack" does not know that on server side there is some "auditing" logic, then maybe it should not be considered as a CQRS violation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the pattern itself has any built in mechanism for this - so as you said "Do you just have to trust that all down stream systems will audit correctly?" - yes.

Just to clarify, are you wanting to audit things like "who viewed what data when" (I.e. user specific data)?  Or are you wanting to audit which messages were sent by which system, when (I.e. system event data)?

Either way, I think maybe you are already doing CQRS even though you have a "tightly bound" central service bus - it all depends on how your classes are designed.  CQRS and CQS are just a mechanism for separating out your code, giving each class single responsibilities.  THe only difference seems to be "CQRS" generally involves "messages" inferring disparate systems, whereas "CQS" seems to infer "method" separation inferring it's within the one application domain.  I think some people make to much of a big deal about having a services bus as a "requirement" for a solution to be considered CQRS.  Check out this explanation for an argument on the potential difference between CQS and CQRS: http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/08/13/command-query-separation/.  At the end of the day, splitting the responsibilities seems to generally be a good idea.

To try and answer your specific questions:

- "does CQRS have a strategy for auditing data access that I don't see?" - no, as a pattern it has no "audit" mechanism.  That is purely up to the implementation of it.
- "is CQRS just for systems where data does not need to be controlled" - no, absolutely not.  I implement CQS/CQRS within "simple" web applications because I think it separates out the code nicely.  See my blog post on this: http://www.nootn.com.au/2013/03/command-query-separation-to-better.html

I know this is probably too late for you but hopefully it helps someone.  I would be interested in hearing other people's thoughts on this also.

Answer (score 1):

As a result of splitting out the commands and queries I've actually found it much easier to log queries in our systems. I opted to use a 'bus' style structure for our queries so I have a central place all queries. This makes it easy to implement cross cutting concerns like logging, security and performance monitoring. I've already found queries that run more often and/or are slower than expected allowing me to optimise. Hope this helps.